# Clear the existing instance of stdin.read_line in rust

Tags: rust, stdin

I am trying to read input lines from the console. I am using the [async_std](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.9.0/async_std/io/struct.Stdin.html) crate for reading the lines.

The `stdin.readline` is called at multiple places.

Is there a way to cancel or flush the previous instance of `stdin.read_line`, before calling trying to read `stdin.read_line` again?

rust code:

```
let create_spawn = async move {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut input_line = String::new();
    
    let r = stdin.read_line(&mut input_line);
    let l = r.await?;
    
    log::debug!("received the input line: {}", input_line);
    Ok::<(), anyhow::Error>(())
};
```

```
    let c1 = tokio::spawn(create_spawn);

    delay();

    // <---cancel the previous instance of `stdin.read_line` --->
    let c2 = tokio::spawn(create_spawn);
```

Comment: Just read lines in a loop until `.read_line` returns `Ok(0)` which indicates no errors with 0 bytes read (which is equivalent to reaching the end of the stream).

Comment: Are you using `tokio` and `async_std`? They are both different async runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you are using [`async_std`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.9.0/async_std/index.html), but your sample is also using [`tokio`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.8.3/tokio/).

Simplifying your program to use `async-std` throughout, and applying a little artistic licence:

```
use async_std::{io, task};
use std::{thread::sleep, time::Duration};

async fn read_from_stdin() -> io::Result<()> {

    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut input_line = String::new();

    println!("Waiting for input");
    let r = stdin.read_line(&mut input_line);
    let n = r.await?;
    
    println!("received the input line ({} bytes): {}", n, input_line);
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {

    let c1 = task::spawn(read_from_stdin());

    sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));

    task::block_on(c1.cancel());

    println!("Cancelled Input!\n");

    let c2 = task::spawn(read_from_stdin());
    
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));

}
```

You can't spawn the same future twice, so I moved your `create_spawn` into an async function called `read_from_stdin`. Each time that function is called it will return a future which completes when a line is read from stdin.

Calls to `task::spawn` return a [`JoinHandle`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.9.0/async_std/task/struct.JoinHandle.html), which exposes a `cancel` method which allows you to cancel the task that you have spawned. You can then spawn a new task to read from stdin.

Comment: I tried to make the changes in my code as suggested here. But unfortunately the app isnt releasing the `stdin.read_line` of `c1`. I have to input a line before I can read the line for `c2`. The same issue i was facing yesterday.

Thanks for your suggestions though!